# Use AJAX to submit data from HTML form to WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, ajax, forms, webmethod

So I'm taking in data from an HTML form and then using AJAX to send the data to a web method to then be sent to a sqlite database, but my AJAX call is failing. What did I mess up? Am I doing it correctly?

HTML Form

```
<form id="addForm" >
     <input type="text"  name="playername" id="playername" placeholder="Player"/> 
     <input type="text" name="points" id="points" placeholder="Points" />
     <input type="text" name="steals" id="steals" placeholder="Steals" />
     <input type="text" name="blocks" id="blocks" placeholder="Blocks" /> 
     <input type="text" name="assists" id="assists" placeholder="Assists" />
     <input type="text" name="mpg" id="mpg" placeholder="MPG" /> 
     <input type="text" name="shotpct" id="shotpct" placeholder="Shot %" />
     <input type="text" name="threepct" id="3pct" placeholder="3 %" /> 
     <input type="button" value="add player" id="addbtn" name="addbtn" />
     </form>
```

AJAX

```
 $("#addbtn").click(function () {
                var form = $("#addForm").serializeArray();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "players.aspx/addRow",
                    data: JSON.stringify(form),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function () {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('failure');
                    }
                });
                    });
```

and the web method(not finished, was just testing to see if I was getting data)

```
[WebMethod]
        public static void addRow(object form)
        {
            var stuff = form;
        }
```

I'm still learning how to use a lot of this stuff so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
type: 'POST',
```

with

```
method: 'POST',
```

dataType: 'json' 
is not needed since you're not receiving data back. The data returned from the server, is formatted according to the dataType parameter.

Also remove JSON.stringify(form),this is already done with the .serialize();

Comment: Yep. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How would I check that the data is being sent?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
JSON.stringify(form)
```

with

```
$('form').serializeArray()
```

So you will have:

```
$("#addbtn").click(function () {
                var form = $("form").serializeArray();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "players.aspx/addRow",
                    data: form,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function () {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('failure');
                    }
                });
                    });
```

If you still get error. there might be a server side problem in the page you are calling. to make sure of that I suggest you use the 'Advanced REST client' witch is a Google Chrome extension and you can test posting values with it and see the result.

Comment: Still getting failure. I thought the "#addForm" was referring to the id of the html form?

Comment: yes you can use it as $('#addForm') too. I edited my answer please have look to the end of my answer.

Comment: I used the exact code you posted and I'm still getting the failure alert. I'll try the Advanced Rest Client.

Comment: I think my server side is working. It's status is "200: OK" when I test the POST, but like I said I don't know if I'm formatting things correctly.

Comment: oh after serializing I had forgotton to add it to your code check the edited answer

Comment: still failing. I'm not sure where to go from here.