# Using jQuery to get multiple checkbox's value and Multiple Delete Using jquery json

Tags: c#, jquery, json, checkbox

I have already bind a html table using jQuery json.
I want to get multiple checkbox value using jQuery json and delete by selected multiple delete method.
This is my code for bind the table.

```
     $(function () {
   debugger
         $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: "WebForm5.aspx/BindDatatable",
             data: "{}",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (dt) {
                 debugger;
                 for (var i = 0; i < dt.d.length; i++) {
                     $("#example1 > tbody").append("<tr><td> <input type='checkbox' /></td><td>" + dt.d[i].CategoryID + "</td><td>" + dt.d[i].Name + "</td><td>" + dt.d[i].Status + "</td><td> <button type='submit'>Submit</button><button type='submit'  onclick='deleteRecord(" + dt.d[i].CategoryID + ")'>Delete</button> </tr>");

                 }
                 $("#example1").DataTable();

             },
             error: function (result) {
                 alert("Error");
             }
         });

     });
```

This is my Button to Delete selected(multiple delete):

```
<button type="button" name="deletebtn" id="deletebtn">Delete Selected</button>
```

This is my html table:

```
    <div class="box-body">
                <button type="button" name="deletebtn" id="deletebtn">Delete Selected</button>
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>

                  <tr>
                    <th>Check Box</th>
                    <th>Category Name</th>
                    <th>Category Details</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>



                  <tbody id="myBody">


                  </tbody>

              </table>

            </div>
```

You just tell me :

1.what is the code to select all the checkbox??

2.Code to delete using multiple jquery??

The Server side Code is here For Single Delete(with out checkbox):

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void deleteRecord(int Id)
    {

        clsCategoryBL objproject = new clsCategoryBL();

        objproject.CategoryDelete(Id);

    }
```

In BL:

```
  public string CategoryDelete(int CategoryID)
    {
        using (KSoftEntities db = new KSoftEntities())
        {
            try
            {

                var categoryDetails = db.tblCategories.Where(i => i.CategoryID == CategoryID).SingleOrDefault();
                db.tblCategories.Remove(categoryDetails);

                db.SaveChanges();
                return "Record deleted successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return "Error on deletion";
        }
    }
```

The Delete is Occur on the Client Side by Using This code:

```
$().ready(function () {

         $('body').on('click', '#deletebtn', function () {
             debugger;
             $("#example1 tr").each(function () {
                 var rowSelector = $(this);
                 if (rowSelector.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked')) {
                     rowSelector.remove();
                 }

             });
         });
     });
```

The Code For Bind The Table:

```
enter code here
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["adminuser"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Page.Title = "Category Details";
            BindDatatable();
        }
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static UserDetails[] BindDatatable()
    {
        clsCategoryBL objcategory = new clsCategoryBL();
        List<UserDetails> details = new List<UserDetails>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //var categories= clsCategoryBL.GetAllCategoryDetails("admin");
        dt = objcategory.GetAllCategoryDetails("admin");
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
            {
                UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
                user.CategoryID = dtrow["CategoryID"].ToString();
                user.Name = dtrow["Name"].ToString();
                user.Status = dtrow["Status"].ToString();
                details.Add(user);
            }
            //literal1.Text = html.ToString();
        }
        return details.ToArray();

    }


 public class UserDetails
    {
        public string CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

I want To delete it on server Side that means also on my database(Sql)
So what should i do???

I Want To Delete Multiple Row By Click On Multiple CheckBox On Database Also..I have mention in above the backend code also..I want to delete the row of html table by click 2 to 3 checkbox(it may be vary depend upon the data) and click Delete Selected button..
The Table structure after pressing f12:

```
enter code here
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="example1_info">
                <thead>

                  <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Check Box: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 204px;">Check Box</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Category Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 276px;">Category Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Category Details: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 293px;">Category Details</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Status: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 148px;">Status</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 211px;">Action</th></tr>
                </thead>



                  <tbody id="myBody">


                  <tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1"> <input type="checkbox"></td><td>42</td><td>xyz</td><td>True</td><td> <button type="submit">Submit</button><button type="submit" onclick="deleteRecord(42)">Delete</button> </td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1"> <input type="checkbox"></td><td>33</td><td>Advertising</td><td>True</td><td> <button type="submit">Submit</button><button type="submit" onclick="deleteRecord(33)">Delete</button> </td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1"> <input type="checkbox"></td><td>31</td><td>Travel &amp; Hospitality</td><td>True</td><td> <button type="submit">Submit</button><button type="submit" onclick="deleteRecord(31)">Delete</button> </td></tr></tbody>

              </table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to delete?

Comment: First of all i want get the multiple checkbox value and i want to delete the multiple row by select the checkbox,when click on Delete multiple...

Comment: Fetching all checkbox can be done by `$("input[type='checkbox']")`.

I still didn't understand what you want to delete

Comment: How to get the value of multiple checkbox ???

Comment: `$("input[type='checkbox']").val();`

Comment: You just write down the details code for select multiple value and what is the jquery code for delete multiple  just like example:http://w3lessons.info/demo/multiple-rows-delete-jquery/      in Delete Selected

Comment: I still don't really get you. If you want to catch all checkboxes that are checked, you can use this code `$("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked")`

Comment: what is the code to delete multiple row???

Comment: i want To delete it on server Side that means also on my database(Sql) So what should i do???
I Want To Delete Multiple Row By Click On Multiple CheckBox On Database Also..I have mention in above the backend code also..I want to delete the row of html table by click 2 to 3 checkbox(it may be vary depend upon the data) and click Delete Selected button..

Comment: Show the markup <td></td> of the HTML please! And I will update answer.

Comment: i have mention above..

Comment: the error is comes in this line if (rowSelector.find(input[type = 'checkbox']).prop('checked')) { uncaughted refrence error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is only one checkbox in a row, you could simply iterate through the rows and post to your existing [WebMethod]

Using the second column as the ID (**EDIT**):

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#deletebtn', function () {

        $("#example1 tr").each(function () {
            var rowSelector = $(this);
            if (rowSelector.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked'))
            {
                //THE MARKUP SHOWING THE ID IS NOT AVAILABLE
                //POST A TABLE ENTRY TO CLEAR UP
                var id = rowSelector.find('td').first().next().html();
                var sendObj = {Id : id};
                //USE JSON OBJECT
                $.ajax({
                    url : "/page.aspx/deleteRecord",//CHANGE TO YOUR URL
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: sendObj,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function () {
                        alert("entry deleted");
                    }
                });
                rowSelector.remove();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**Explanation**

Using JQuery you simply iterate through each row and look for the checkbox value. Note you will iterate through the header as well, so if there is a checkbox there *you must add logic to skip the first iteration*.

**EDIT 3:** You will also post the ID to the server if the checkbox is checked. *Important to note that you would rather post a single bulk array of ID's instead of multiple single posts, but that method has not been exposed or posted here.*

Good Luck

CODE SNIPPET (CLIENT SIDE ONLY)

```js
$().ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#deletebtn', function () {
            $("#example1 tr").each(function () {
                var rowSelector = $(this);
                if (rowSelector.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked'))
                {
                    rowSelector.remove();
                }

            });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id='deletebtn'>DELETE</button>
  
  <table id='example1'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>CHECKBOX</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' value='check' /></td>
      <td>the name</td>
      <td>the description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' value='check' /></td>
      <td>the name</td>
      <td>the description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' value='check' /></td>
      <td>the name</td>
      <td>the description</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is not working Sir...Is there any other way...Can you write down code???

Comment: Will make snippet, stand by.

Comment: Open the developer tools "F12" in your browser and check for relevant errors? Then post them in your question.

We've got a bit of language barrier, did I not answer the right question?

Comment: The code is working on the client side but server side the code is not working....

Comment: Did not know that was a requirement, Could you elaborate on what you are using at the back end? You will have to post an ID array to the back end. Or you will have to bind the datatable differently.

Comment: Sir I Want To Delete Multiple Row By Click On Multiple CheckBox On Database Also..I have mention in above the backend code also..I want to delete the row of html table by click 2 to 3 checkbox(it may be vary depend upon the data) and click Delete Selected button..on So How to pass id..OR what should i do???

Comment: I have updated the code. But i need to see a row entry so that we can get the ID. Can you post the row entry?

Comment: i ahve also upadate the code..what is  applicableID?? How to get the checkbox id? i Don't understand this line...url : "/page.aspx/deleteRecord?Id=" + rowSelector.find("#applicableID").val(),

Comment: That is where to find the Id of the of the row entry. That is why I need you to post the HTML markup of what a record looks like. Press F12 and look in the <td></td> inside your table, then I can show you the way.

Comment: It is the html table. I need to see it once it has rows.

Comment: the error is comes in this line   if (rowSelector.find(input[type = 'checkbox']).prop('checked')) {     uncaughted refrence error

Comment: The "input[type='chexkbox']" must be in quotation marks - edited. But I still need to see the html table.

Comment: i have mention in the above..the html table

Comment: Okay edited with the second column as ID. (That is what it looks like from what i can tell from the code.)

Comment: the row is deleted on the client side browser..but when reload it will once again show in table..

Comment: Place alert(id); before you do the ajax post, to see if the correct id is being found

Comment: Also, debug the WebMethod see if the ID is being retrieved.

Comment: no the id is not available..in client side the id is available as an a popup window but in .aspx.cs page i.e. webmothod the id is not passing

Comment: the id is not retrieve on webmethod

Comment: Well since you are getting the ID on the client side, my advice to you would be to search on the site for the correct way to post to a webmethod, start <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254312/use-ajax-to-submit-data-from-html-form-to-webmethod">here</a> perhaps

Comment: is there any other way??

Answer (score 0):

A easier method will be if you give a class to all the check-boxes in your form and then on button click you simply iterate through all the check-boxes using the class, and therby seralizing their values.
`var values = $("#Myform").find(".CheckBoxClass").serialize();`
here the variable `value` will contain the values of all the checkboxes in your form and you can send them using ajax on your server to perform further action.

Comment: You just write down the code clearly...So that i can understand...I have mention everything(html table,jquery script code...),So you just tell me what should i write down in my script and what is the code to select multiple checkbox(how to get value) and what is the code to delete by click on Delete Selected button???

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below mentioned.

$("example1 input:checkbox").prop('checked',this.checked);

Or it is answered already in below post

[jquery set all checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774029/jquery-set-all-checkbox-checked)