# how to send form data by ajax from asp.net html page to c# code

Tags: asp.net

I want to get from post value in my class method via ajax call
here is my html page

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text"  />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="date" name="date" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" />
</form>
```

And this is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var data = $(this).serializeArray();
            var jsObj = {};
            $.each(data, function (feild, value) {
                jsObj[value.name] = value.value;
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "index.cs/addRow",
                method: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: jsObj,
                success : function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
 });
```

And this is my c# code 
these is the method where i want post form

```
[WebMethod] 
public static void addRow(object form)
{
  var stuff = form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `url` parameter seems to be wrong (it should reference to ASPX page instead of code-behind file), also if the response is not JSON better to opt out `dataType: 'json'` definition. Try handling submit button's `click` event instead waiting for form submission like example below:

**Markup (ASPX)**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text"  />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="date" name="date" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="send" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var formData = $('form').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.aspx/addRow',
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            // do something
        },
        // error handling
    });
});
```

**Note 1:** `$.each(data, function (feild, value) { ... })` is unnecessary because `serializeArray()` already contains form objects.

**Note 2:** If the form data is unchanged before `POST`, I suggest you using `serialize()` instead of `serializeArray()`.

Related: [Use AJAX to submit data from HTML form to WebMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254312/use-ajax-to-submit-data-from-html-form-to-webmethod)